# Is there a way to use a DexClassLoader without using reflection *everywhere*?

Tags: android, classloader

I have a library that I plan on using in dex form.  I want to compile directly against this library, but not export it.  Instead I want to drop it in my resources and use a class loader to actually instantiate it.

So here's my library:

```
public class Foo {
  public doFoo(String message) {
  }

  public doFoo(int count, String message) {
  }
}
```

Now I want to call `doFoo()`.  A lot.  More than it's probably reasonable to use reflection for.  Right now it works with:

```
public class FooConsumer {
  private final DexClassLoader fooLoader;

  public FooConsumer(DexClassLoader fooLoader) {
    this.fooLoader = fooLoader;
  }

  public void go() {
    Class<?> fooClass = fooLoader.loadClass("com.library.Foo");
    Object fooInstance = fooClass.newInstance();
    Method fooMethodDoFoo = fooClass.getMethod("doFoo", String.class);
    fooMethodDoFoo.invoke(fooInstance, "Hello World");
  }
```

This is obviously fugly.  Especially since I haven't included any of the exception handling, as there are half a dozen throwables to catch in there.  I could cache a bunch of stuff, helping me with speed a bit, but not a lot.

Normally I'd have both aware of a third library that has an interface, but the library has some static methods and I can't edit it anyway.  It'd be really nice if I could do something like:

```
public class FooConsumer {
  private FooAccessor accessor;

  public FooConsumer(DexClassLoader fooLoader) {
    Object fooInstance = fooLoader.loadClass("com.library.Foo").newInstance();
    Log.i("TEST", "fooInstance: " + fooInstance);
    this.accessor = new FooAccessor(fooInstance);
  }

  public void go() {
    accessor.doFoo("Hello World");
  }

  private static class FooAccessor {
    private Foo fooInstance;

    public FooAccessor(Object instance) {
      fooInstance = (Foo)instance;
    }

    public void doFoo(String message) {
      fooInstance.doFoo(message);
    }
  }
}
```

See what I did there?  The inner class is just a wrapper around the Foo object, I've linked against it, but not exported it, and all is good in the world.  But it doesn't work.  In logcat I get

```
I/TEST: fooInstance: com.library.Foo@413b1b68
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.library.Foo
  ...
```

Is there a way to have FooAccessor use the class loader I passed in?  Or is the use of class loaders a damnation into reflection hell.

Comment: Just to head off the obvious question, I'm doing this because I want to be able to pull backwards compatible upgrades for Foo as they are available instead of having to push a whole new version of my app.

Comment: Check out this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one.  It doesn't cover being able to use static methods, and it relies on being in control of the library, which I am unfortunately not.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, rolled off the project :-(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this gist.

https://gist.github.com/nickcaballero/7045993

It uses reflection to merge the new DexClassLoader to in-stock BaseDexClassLoader.